# Sending dynamic content to watson assistant

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I am new to `Watson Assistant`. I am working on their `nodejs  car_workspace`

My requirement is to capture an employee number and send information about that employee through the Chatbot.

`So first I need to capture the employee num in the nodejs code. 
And then get the required data from a predefined array.
And finally, pass this to the Chabot for the requestor to see.`

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The employee number you capture from chatbot can be stored in a context variable and then passed to the application side to get dynamic data. Documentation below will help you get started to build a client application by maintaining state
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/develop-app.html#building-a-client-application

You can also make programmatic calls to external applications or services and get back a result as part of the processing that occurs within a dialog turn.https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions

Please refer to sample apps listed out in Watson Assistant documentation to understand it better https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/sample-applications.html#sample-apps
https://developer.ibm.com/code/patterns/create-cognitive-retail-chatbot